# How to include client certificate in ReactJS requests to an external REST API which requires mutual TLS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, axios

I am new to reactJS and I'm trying to add mutual TLS to a web application which is built on reactJS and node.js framework. I'm calling an external REST API which requires a client certificate; so, I believe that I need to send the cert along with my request. Additionally, the application uses axios interceptors to intercept the urls from sub-modules and prepend service base url.

I have tried to read the client cert and its key in the interceptor function but the framework is not allowing me to read file from that client location. It instead throws an error "fs.readFileSync is not a function" to the console.

```
//api.js

import axios from 'axios';

const serviceUrl = 'https://<<rest api endpoint>>'
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  if (!config.url.includes('http') && !config.url.includes('/__env')) {
    config.url = `${serviceUrl}${config.url}`
    config.withCredentials = true
    config.credentials = 'same-origin'
    config.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            cert: fs.readFileSync("./web.client.chain.pem"),
            key: fs.readFileSync("./web.client.key.pem")
     })
  }
  return config
})
```

With the above code, I see "fs.readFileSync is not a function" error which I suppose is indicating that fs cannot be used from this location.

I would appreciate any help in addressing the following question:

1. How to enable fs and read files from the client location (e.g. api.js).
2. If #1 is not possible is there any alternative way to send the certs using axios?

Comment: Hi @Michael Afewerki, did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use file system functions in the browser. When you send a request out to a server, your certificate is sent along with it. If the server is running express.js, for example, you can get the certificate with req.connection.getPeerCertificate().